# Remove new line when echo '<'$env:UserName'>'

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, echo

is there a way to remove a new line when running this command:

```
echo '<'$env:UserName'>'
```

When I type that I get output:

```
<
username>
```

I want it to be `<username>` without the break. Like this:

```
<username>
```

Answer (score 3):

just:

```
echo "<$env:UserName>"
```